# Is there a way to use SFINAE to detect if a type implements a given abstract base class?

Tags: c++, interface, sfinae

Here's the simple use-case for this question.  (Note:  I realize the code-patterns shown here may not be considered best-practices; the example code is meant only to be illustrative of the topic at hand)

Currently, I have this handy little templated function that will allocate a copy of any arbitrary given object from the heap, and return that copy:

```
template<typename T> inline T * CloneStaticObject(const T & item) 
{
   return new T(item);
}
```

Works great for any type with a copy-constructor... until I pass in a reference-to-a-base-class type, and then I get bit by object-slicing problems.

So to handle that, I've also got a nice little OOP-style cloning interface that I can use, complete with a `CloneDynamicObject(const ICloneable &)` function that will correctly clone any object that inherits from `ICloneable`, regardless of what the type of the passed-in reference is:

```
class ICloneable
{
public:
   virtual ~ICloneable() {/* empty */}

   virtual ICloneable Clone() const = 0;
};

class MyBaseClass : public ICloneable
{
public:
   MyBaseClass() {/* empty */}

   virtual ICloneable * Clone() const {return new MyBaseClass(*this);}      
};

class MySubClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
   MySubClass() {/* empty */}

   virtual ICloneable * Clone() const {return new MySubClass(*this);}      
};

template<typename T> inline T * CloneDynamicObject(const T & item) 
{
   return static_cast<T *>(item.Clone());
}
```

... this also works great, as long as I am careful to only pass it an argument that is a reference-to-an-ICloneable-object.

But now creeping elegance has set in, and I want to make a `CloneAnyObject(const T & item)` function that will do the right thing no matter what, e.g.:

```
 // This doesn't work but it shows the idea
 template<typeName T> inline T * CloneAnyObject(const T & item)
 {
    const ICloneable * cloneMe = dynamic_cast<const ICloneable *>(&item);
    if (cloneMe) return CloneDynamicObject(*cloneMe)
            else return CloneStaticObject(item);
 }
```

... the above implementation *almost* does what I want, except there are two problems with it:

1. `dynamic_cast<>` doesn't work on all types
2. Even if it did, `dynamic_cast()` tests the object at run-time, and if possible I'd like to avoid that overhead by having the test-for-ICloneability be evaluated at compile-time instead.

My question is, is there any way to use SFINAE to implement the `CloneAnyObject()` function properly?

(Note that I'm aware of the SFINAE trick for testing if a typename has a method with a given name, and I think it's a very useful technique, but that's not quite what I'm looking for here; what I'm looking for instead is a way to test if a type inherits from an interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [std::is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) trait to statically determine if a type is derived from another. It can be used as follows to split your function into one version for derived types and one for other types:

```
// For derived types
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<ICloneable, T>, int> = 0>
inline T * CloneAnyObject(const T & item) {
    return CloneDynamicObject(item);
}

// For non-derived types (note the !)
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<ICloneable, T>, int> = 0>
inline T * CloneAnyObject(const T & item) {
    return CloneStaticObject(item);
}
```

If you're using C++17, you can also simplify this using `if constexpr` as seen in [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417319/1922722)'s answer.

Comment: `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` definitely seem like the right tools for the job, but in your example code it appears that `dynamic_cast` is still being used, and hence the classification is being done at run-time.  I've been trying to figure out how to create two templated `CloneAnyObject()` functions, one that would be called for `ICloneable` objects and the other that would be called for non-`ICloneable` objects, but I haven't figured out how to make that happen; do you have any idea about how to do that?

Comment: Ah, I see. The updated code should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: You did a common mistake: default template parameter are not part of signature, so you declare twice the same function, with different definition. use `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0` (or similar) instead of `typename = std::enable_it_t<cond>`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although since I'm targetting C++11, I can't use `enable_if_t`, so I had to modify it a bit, to this:  `template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Cloneable, T>::value, T*>::type CloneAnyObject(const T& item) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

You may have 2 overloads:

```
template <typeName T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<ICloneable , T>::value, T*> /* SFINAE */
CloneAnyObject(const T& item)
{
    return CloneDynamicObject(item);
}

template <typeName T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<ICloneable , T>::value, T*> /* SFINAE */
CloneAnyObject(const T& item)
{
    return CloneStaticObject(item);
}
```

With C++17, you might do

```
template <typeName T>
T* CloneAnyObject(const T& item)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of<ICloneable, T>::value) {
        return CloneDynamicObject(item);
    } else {
        return CloneStaticObject(item);
    }
}
```